# c++ - passing value from one function to another

Tags: c++

This probably is very simple, but I can't get it working. Generally the code is supposed to calculate salary1 in first function, then salary2 using first function in second function, and display the result in main function. However, depending on how I try to modify it I get "unidentified variable salary1 used" or the output is 0.00. This is the basic version, I tried modifying it in various ways, and I've run out of ideas. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
float pay1(float, int);
float pay2(float);


int main()
{
//variables, cin etc., all the obvious stuff
//

salary2 = pay2(salary1);
cout << "salary2:" << salary2;
}


float pay1 (float daily, int days)
{
float salary1 = daily*days;
return 0;
}

float pay2 (float salary1)
{
float salary2 = 0.7*salary1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You `return 0` you should `return salery1` and `return salery2`

Answer (score 0):

You should return the salary2 not 0

```
float pay2 (float salary1)
{
float salary2 = 0.7*salary1;
return 0;//This is mistake you are returning 0
return salary2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you aren't returning the correct values from your functions; you are just returning 0. You should return `salary1` from the first function, `pay1` and return `salary2` from `pay2`. I'm assuming you've declared the variables `salary1` and `salary2` earlier in main and just omitted them from the question but, if not, you will have to declare them in main.

Answer (score 0):

```
salary2 = pay2(salary1);  // Here you need to pass some value,
```

As `salary1` is not define before this that's why its giving error `"unidentified variable salary1`

you can use, for example

```
float salary1 = 1000.0;   //define variable
salary2 = pay2(salary1);
```

Or

```
salary2 = pay2(1000.0);
```

And

```
float pay2 (float salary1)
{
    float salary2 = 0.7*salary1;
    //return 0;  // As here you are returning `0` so it will give `0.00` as Output.
    return salary2; // It will return value of salary2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you should be doing

```
float pay1(float, int);
float pay2(float);

int main()
{
    float daily = 100; //whatever number you want, obviously
    int days = 10; //same
    float salary1 = pay1(daily, days);
    // here salary1 is 1000
    float salary2 = pay2(salary1);
    // here salary2 is 700
    cout << "salary1:" << salary1<<"\n";
    cout << "salary2:" << salary2<<"\n";
    return 0;
}


float pay1 (float daily, int days)
{
    return daily*days;
}

float pay2 (float salary1)
{
    return 0.7*salary1;
}
```

Comment: well that doesn't work at all because "error: pay2 doesn't take 2 arguments"

Comment: that's what I worked out as well ... but now there is another issue. Salary1 is correct, however, I also wanted to display salary1, and it is 1000.00, as defined earlier. it's funny because e.g. for daily, days=10, I get salary2=70.00 and salary1=1000.00, while salary 2 is supposed to be calculated as 0.7*salary1

Comment: and it still displays 1000 instead of e.g. 100 for daily, days=10. But I got it working with cout<<daily*days

Comment: that doesn't make any sense, there is a bug in your code, trust me. wtv

Comment: I see that there is something wrong... but if it gives the right result, it's part of the success :)